# Turn a reference link into the real target url - Producthunt API, python

Tags: python, api, selenium, url

I am working on a small project around gathering the beauty of the Producthunt API. Sincerely, it only offers a reference link with producthunt mask for the products own website and I need it in the as the proper target URL.

i.e.

current URL: `https://www.producthunt.com/r/f8ec7ea9f567ca`

How the URL should look like: `https://www.olvin.com/?ref=producthunt`

Currently, I am thinking to use selenium in order to visit the respective ref link and retrieve the current URL. Is there an easier way you could think of?

I am working with Python.